# How to add Sum of amount from a sub-level to its parent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data which is selected from two tables.

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRHC8.png)

I want to add sum of amount of sub level to its parent for example level 3 two entries are added to level 2 and sum of all level 2 entries be added to level 1 and finally total is added to level 0.

following is table structure and data

```
create table `bills` (
    `id` int (11),
    `description` varchar (75),
    `amount` float ,
    `sortid` float ,
    `lvl` int (11)
); 
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('1','Utilities',NULL,'1','0');
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('2','  Gas and Electric',NULL,'1.1','1');
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('3','     Gas','50','1.11','2');
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('4','     Electric','100','1.12','2');
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('5','     Telephone','90','1.13','2');
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('6','        Phone 1','30','1.131','3');
insert into `bills` (`id`, `description`, `amount`, `sortid`, `lvl`) values('7','        Phone 2','40','1.132','3');
```

Comment: I am open to stored procedure and SQL queries. Maybe with Recursive or Windows Functions. Performance is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to do with the recursive CTE, since aggregation is required to calculate the sum over sublevels, which is not allowed in the recursive part of the CTE.

So, you can use subquery or `LEFT JOIN` the table with self to get the sum of `amount` values for all rows with `lvl` values greater than the current one.

Using subquery example

```
SELECT
    b.*,
    (SELECT 
         SUM(amount) 
     FROM bills b2 
     WHERE b2.lvl > b.lvl 
           AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.sortid, '.', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(b2.sortid, '.', 1)
    ) lvl_total
FROM bills b
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` example

```
SELECT
    b.*,
    SUM(b2.amount) lvl_total
FROM bills b
LEFT JOIN bills b2 ON b2.lvl > b.lvl
                      AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.sortid, '.', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(b2.sortid, '.', 1)
GROUP BY b.id
```

Both queries produce the same results.

| id | description | amount | sortid | lvl | lvl_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Utilities | NULL | 1 | 0 | 310 |
| 2 | Gas and Electric | NULL | 1.1 | 1 | 310 |
| 3 | Gas | 50 | 1.11 | 2 | 70 |
| 4 | Electric | 100 | 1.12 | 2 | 70 |
| 5 | Telephone | 90 | 1.13 | 2 | 70 |
| 6 | Phone 1 | 30 | 1.131 | 3 | NULL |
| 7 | Phone 2 | 40 | 1.132 | 3 | NULL |
| 8 | Top Ups | 50 | 2 | 0 | 50 |
| 9 | Mobilink | 50 | 2.1 | 1 | NULL |

You need the `id` column to be the primary key.  Also you need to create a covering index `index(amount,lvl)` to improve query performance.

You can test them on real data to find the best one. I suppose that subquery would the best.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b05ec00cff3e9a03ec9b3c9748d7b80e)*

Comment: I appreciate the answer. However I forgot to mention before that there could be more than one set of accounts sharing the same value for level. Please check this fiddle, I've added two more records for testing. Sum of both set of levels should be separate.    https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4566960d7e03632f0083b45c1a5de0d

Comment: @Nabil, I've updated my answer according to your comment